# What volume is enclosed by $k$ evenly-spaced, overlapping American footballs whose axes are diameters of a unit sphere?

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, volume

Take $k \in \Bbb N$ intersecting American footballs and configure them inside a unit sphere such that each football touches two opposite ends of the sphere. Each of the shapes are spaced evenly apart.

In the case $k\to \infty$ the volume should be equal to the volume of a sphere.

[Related Problem (intersection of $n$ congruent cylinders).](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154386/the-intersection-of-n-cylinders-in-3-dimensional-space)

I want to tackle the case $k=2$ first. So I'm using "Cavalieri's Lemon" which is the surface of revolution of a parabolic arc, to model a football.

The equation for the parabolic arc to be revolved about the $x-$axis is: $f(x)=x(1-x).$

> What is the volume in the region where the (two) footballs overlap?

[image]

I've calculated that the volume of one football is $\frac{\pi}{30}.$ If the interior shape is a well-known shape I can proabably search for the volume of that shape, but I'm having trouble visualizing the interior shape with the enclosed volume.

Comment: Sorry, what is an American football, mathematically? The intersection of two spheres looks like a convex lens (or a lentil), not an American football.

Comment: @user856 I think the American football is defined via the solid of revolution as stated in the question

Comment: What does it mean to have the footballs spaced evenly apart, while intersecting each other?

Comment: for k=2 it means that the 4 points that touch the sphere, define a square

Comment: for k=4 it means that the 8 points that touch the sphere, define a cube

Comment: Evenly distributing $k$ polar axes on the sphere is not well-defined without more clarification. What should this look like when $k=17$?

Comment: I will change the question to allow only even $k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the axes of the footballs are perpendicular to each other, e.g., $$(y^2 + z^2) = (1/4 - x^2)^2, \\ (x^2 + z^2) = (1/4 - y^2)^2.$$ Then we are looking for the volume common to their intersection.  We are searching for the value of $x = y = c > 0$ when $z = 0$ corresponding to the intersection of the curves $y = 1/4 - x^2$, $x = 1/4 - y^2$, which is of course at $(x,y) = (c,c)$ where $c = \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$.  Hence the volume corresponds to the  integral
$$\begin{align}
V &= 16 \int_{x=0}^c \int_{y=x}^{1/4-x^2} \sqrt{(1/4 - x^2)^2 - y^2} \, dy \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_{x=0}^c \left(1-4 x^2\right)^2\left( \pi - 2 \tan ^{-1}\frac{4
   x}{\sqrt{16 x^4-24 x^2+1}}\right) - 8 x \sqrt{16 x^4-24 x^2+1}  \, dx \\
&= \frac{2\pi + 16 \log 2 - 13}{60} \\
&\approx 0.0728923.
\end{align}$$